# jquery file upload with ssl and php. Proper .htaccess?

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, ssl

I'm using jquery file upload for some time and it I find it great but whenever I try to upload files with ssl turned on I've got an 'unknown error' on page and bunch of weird GET requests. I'm almost certain it's due to some missconfiguration in .htaccess file

This is what I use:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.pl
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.pl/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Needless to say uploads work fine as soon as all the rewrites are disabled even if I stay on page with https in address

I would be much obliged for any help